# I am trying to click the Link to open dialog box in selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, junit4

Here is my Html Code:

```
<a id="expTo" class="formblue_link padRight10 exportLinkActive" 
      href="javascript:;" style="display: block; margin-left: -50px; margin- bottom: -20px;"> Export To </a>
```

I tried below Code:

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("expTo"))).click();
```

But I am unable to click on the link.

Comment: This is not a link text. Actual link text is `" Export To "`,

Comment: If you use `linkText` then it means the text. Try `linkText(
"Export To")`

Answer (score 2):

If you are locating element using `id` attribute value of the link element, It should be [`By.id()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id-java.lang.String-) instead as :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("expTo"))).click();
```

Or if you want to locate element using [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-), you should try to pass exact `innerText` of the link element as :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(" Export To "))).click();
```

*Note*:- As I'm seeing in your provided `HTML` for link element's `innerText` has extra spaces, in this case if you are using [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-), you have to pass element's `innerText` with extra spaces as well. If there extra spaces is present, you can also try using [`By.partialLinkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#partialLinkText-java.lang.String-) to pass only visible text without using spaces as :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Export To"))).click();
```

**Edited**

> It is inside IFrame Saurabh. How can I try to click?

If this element is inside an `iframe`, you need to switch that `iframe` before finding element as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

//Now switch to iframe 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframe id or name"));

//Now find desire element click 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("expTo"))).click();

//After doing all stuff inside iframe switch back to default content for further steps
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh. I tried above code. But it throwing error message.  TimeoutException: Expected Condition Failed: Waiting for the element to be clickable: By.linkText

Comment: @kurri make sure desired element is not inside any `frame/iframe` element??

Comment: It is inside IFrame Saurabh. How can I try to click?

Comment: @kurri Ok then before finding desired element you need to switch that frame as `driver.switchTo().frame("iframe id or name")`